# Invoke plugin method in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, plugins, error-handling

I want to implement a plugin in which i define a method for throwing Error. The method will be used in different components. for example if a button is clicked or a given value is <0. I tried it in App.vue.

- I want to check if some buttons are working correctly. So if they arent, like
  if(!event){ throwingError("msg")}
- I also aiming for some value comparison with error throwing

Right now i cant invoke the method in App.vue and im not quite sure.

My Plugin:

```
  const throwingError = {}
  throwingError.install = function (Vue){
  Vue.mixin({
  LogEvent(value, msg){
    try {
      if(event){
        throw new Error(msg)
      }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error Message": error.message)
              }
            }
         });
       }

   export default throwingError
```

In my main.js i imported the plugin

```
import throwingError from "./plugin/throwingError
Vue.use(throwingError)
```

My App.vue:

```
   <template>
    <div id="app">
     <button v-on:click="LogEvent($event, 'hi')">
      Click to trigger throwingError method
     </button>
     </div>
    </template>
     <script>
          import throwingError from './plugins/throwingError'
          export default{
          mounted() {
           throwingError(event, "test")
          },
       };
     </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your plugin creates a mixin, you don't need to import the plugin into your components, and generally you wouldn't do so with any plugin.  But there are some syntax errors and a missing `methods` option.  Try this:

```js
const throwingError = {}
throwingError.install = function (Vue){
  Vue.mixin({
    methods: {  // You missed this, `LogEvent` is a method
      LogEvent(event, msg){  // This had a wrong argument name
        try {
          if(event){
            throw new Error(msg)
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error Message:", error.message); // This syntax was wrong
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
Vue.use(throwingError);

/***** APP *****/
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  mounted() {
    this.LogEvent({}, 'test'); // This was missing the method name
  }
});

Vue.config.productionTip = false;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button v-on:click="LogEvent($event, 'hi')">
    Click to trigger throwingError method
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Dan! It worked for me after some little changes. My plugin had some global methods declared. After i tried your recommend way, it stopped working. The solution was to just export the whole plugin. In main.js i had to import and write Vue.use(plugin)